# Filter model based of context data using django filter

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a detail view of a model that I want to display together with a list of products and Im trying to integrate django_filter within this view.

#### Error Message

> TypeError at /collections/christmas/?category=mens, 
>   get context data takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

#### Filter

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['categories']
```

#### Detail View

```
class collection_detail(DetailView):
    model = Collection
      def get_context_data(self, request, **kwargs):
       context = super(collection_detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['collection_list'] = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.filter(collection=self.object.id).filter(structure='parent'))
       return context
```

#### How i intend it to work

The category filter is pre-defined in a list of links, so when the user clicks on a collection related to a specific category the url of the detail view would look like /collections/christmas/?category=mens .

What am I specifically doing wrong here? Is it possible to even do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `*args` in your overridden method.

```
class collection_detail(DetailView):
    model = Collection

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(collection_detail, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['collection_list'] = ProductFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.filter(collection=self.object.id).filter(structure='parent'))
        return context
```

Comment: I added it in but now it mentioned that there is an error global name 'request' is not defined

Comment: Ah, should be `self.request`

Comment: interesting it works, but there is an error in the templates, 'ProductFilter' object is not iterable, interesting, I thought i would be possible to get a list of the products using django_filters

Comment: in the template you need to use `.all`: `collection_list.all`